# Is it possible to add a script to a spreadsheet you create in a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know it's a long shot however, do you know if it is possible to attach a script to a spreadsheet you create in a script?

pseudo code version would be

```
function create_spreadsheet

new spreadsheet = ... creates spreadsheet

new spreadsheet = ... fills with appropriate formatting

-Need help part is -
new spreadsheet add script = ... Attach Following script to the new spreadsheet.
-Need help part is -
```

Comment: If you will create a copy of an existing spreadsheet it contain the scripts. Will it help to your case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a Google apps script to a spreadsheet created using the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218847/how-can-i-add-a-google-apps-script-to-a-spreadsheet-created-using-the-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not gotten to try it yet, but rather than creating a spreadsheet you could copy a public version of a spreadsheet that includes the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AppsScript REST API (aka "advanced API") to programmatically manage AppsScript projects.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects  This includes the ability to create "bound" projects (i.e., bound to a specific Sheet) and upload new content to that project's files.

However, to use the REST API from AppsScript code you'll need to enable the "advanced API".  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced.