# How to create a new Spreadsheet with a connected script within an App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Within a Standalone App ScriptI'm creating a new spread sheet using the following line:

```
var new_ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("File_Name");
```

Now I wanna link a predefined App Script to this spreadsheet. How to do this? I couldn't find any method within the Documentation or by searching Google

I found the ScriptApp, but it doesn't provide any methods. I also found the API, but i don't think its available within App Script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add a script to a spreadsheet you create in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268729/is-it-possible-to-add-a-script-to-a-spreadsheet-you-create-in-a-script)

Comment: Maybe this other one is better as "possible duplicate of" [How can I add a Google apps script to a spreadsheet created using the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13218847/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer and bacuase I haven't find it, I change my approach. I created a script bound to a Google Sheet. When a new Google Sheet is needed I make a copy of the "template" Google Sheet with the bound script. I have a sheet name Parameters so the users can control the bound script.